# Prove Catalan's Identity

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I need to prove the following Identity 
$$\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}=1-\frac12+\frac13-\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}$$
Which in compact form is: $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{n+j}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$

I can also express the previous equality as:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{n+j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac1{2j-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac1{2j}$$
However I can't seem to go any further. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Use mathematical induction.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought about that, however, I don't think my book wants mathematical induction, it wants me to work with properties of sums (operations of summations). Also, math induction is explained chapters after the one I found the exercise on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + j} & =
\sum_{j = 1 + n}^{2n}{1 \over j} =
\sum_{j = 1}^{2n}{1 \over j} - \sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over j} =
\bracks{\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j} + \sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j - 1}} - 2\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j - 1} - \sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j} =
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{j = 1}^{2n}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over j}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain what you did on your third step? I can see that is is true but I don't see how you went from one to the other. Thank you! Specifically: $\sum_{j=1}^{2n}\frac1j=\sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j} + \sum_{j = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2j - 1}$

Comment: @DMH16 You can partition the integers between $1$ and $2n$ into the set of odd ones and the set of even ones